# Return Value Optimization in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, return-value-optimization

I have the following code:

```
struct return_values {
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> a;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> b;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> c;
};

return_values foo() {
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> a = barA();
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> b = barB();
    std::shared_ptr<SomeType> c = barC();
    return return_values{a,b,c};
}
```

To my understanding the copy constructor would be called for a, b and c when calling the constructor for return_value and copy elision is only applied for the temporary return_values object itself. However, the above code seems to be faster than

```
return return_values{std::move(a),std::move(b),std::move(c)};
```

Which in my mind should be faster, as copy constructur of shared_ptr would not be called. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You could just use `return {barA(), barB(), barC()};`

Comment: Yes that seems to be as as fast as  `return return_values{a,b,c};` but why is that faster than move? Sorry if that is a stupid question.

Comment: `move` most likely forces temporaries to be created whereas without it the compiler can optimize them away.  `return move(...)` is normally an optimization loss, not a win.  There are very few cases where it is actually required.

Comment: Can you provide a proper benchmark, e.g. using quick-bench? On both GCC/libstdc++ and Clang/libc++ the code generated with `std::move` looks much simpler (although I haven't benchmarked): https://godbolt.org/z/4Kvs93zTT

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see any point where creation of temporary would be possible (at least since C++17). `std::move` only changes whether the initialization of the members in the aggregate initialization uses the copy or move constructor of `std::shared_ptr`. It is not applied directly to the `return` operand and should therefore be fine.

Comment: @user17732522 Agreed. @Tox How do you get the conclusion "the above code seems to be faster"? Copy for `std::shared_ptr` can't be avoided.

Comment: I did not really benchmark it in an isolated way, but I had a unit test, which calls the above code in each iteration of a large for loop and the runtime of the test between the two version consistently differs by a few hundred ms